# how to concatenate strings in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to concatenate some strings in a Jenkinsfile but it's not working:

```
def versionFromFile = readFile("./version")
def version = versionFromFile + env.BUILD_NUMBER
```

I tried other solutions as well:

```
sh "echo version: ${version}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
sh "git tag ${version}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

but ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} is not evaluated/printed

if I do

```
sh "git tag 1.0.1-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

${env.BUILD_NUMBER} is evaluated/printed

I still don't get how the scripting language works inside the Jenkinsfile, the documentation is all about the DSL, does that means that you can't do common scripting operations?

Comment: I don't think you need to use def when defining variables in a Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 6):

Does this work?

```
versionFromFile = readFile("./version")
sh "git tag ${versionFromFile}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

assuming that versionFromFile is read from the file correctly of course. To test that isn't your problem, you could just define it like this

```
versionFromFile = "99"
sh "git tag ${versionFromFile}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

Answer (score 6):

Jenkinsfiles follows the same syntax as Groovy language (with some exceptions). See [Jenkins syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)

The way to concatenate strings in a Jenkinsfile is using the plus character ("+"). For example:

```
VAR1 = "THIS IS"
VAR2 = 4
RESULT = VAR1 + " " + VAR2 + " " + PARAM

echo "$RESULT"
```

Then if `PARAM` is an input parameter with the value "YOU" then the printed output is:

"THIS IS 4 YOU"

Then regarding your problem with environment variable `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` try to simply use `BUILD_NUMBER` instead.