# JenkinsFile parameters settings for key:value pair not allowing strings

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to set a variable for a key value pairing in a jenkinsfile and can't get it to recognize the variable as a string.

```
zip = "name_of_zip_file_to_use"
createZipFile = [src:"./test", destination:"./"+zip+".zip"]
```

I have tried to use the variable zip as the whole string also but nothing seems to work.  I'm not sure why it isn't recognizing the destination value variable as a string.  Any ideas why I can't get this to work in the jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing and interpolating variable is possible this way - using `${VARIABLE_NAME}` syntax. So in your case it would look:

```
zip = "name_of_zip_file_to_use"
createZipFile = [src:"./test", destination:"./${zip}.zip"]
```

---

If interested more about referencing variables and/or a string concatenation, see docs or similar StackOverflow topics:

- variable interpolation in groovy: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation and http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation
- [how to concatenate strings in a Jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803382/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-a-jenkinsfile)

Comment: Still get the error: ERROR: Please provide valid value of createZipFiles in Jenkinsfile. Aborting Build!!

Comment: Could you share how does your pipeline look like?  Where exactly are you using this piece of code (JSL, pipeline steps? stages? is your pipeline scripted or declarative?) otherwise it's hard to guess what might be the root cause.